# Python/pandas: Iterating through area of interest with multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have **multiple** dataframes/2d-arrays that represent infrared (IR) images similar to this picture

[Heatmap of Dataframe/Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzDlM.png)

Now I want to iterate over a specific area of interest with it's values, assuming the area would be in the center of the 2D-array as shown in this image.

[Heatmap with the Area of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEX7p.png)

I am assuming I will need to iterate through the specific coordinates (x,y) of the array. Then I want to create new dataframes with the values and follow with some statistics. Is there a function/specific design to do that?

I am fairly new to Python so I appreciate every tip.

EDIT: Solved it with a for loop and dataframe.truncate() function.

Comment: as it stands, this question is likely going to be closed as too broad. you should try to solve the problem yourself first, post the code that you used to attempt to solve the problem and what your _specific_ problem with that code is.

Comment: Hey @FABeng, welcome to SO. Would you be able to post your df, as well as code you have tried running? This increases the chance of your question getting an answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry I thought I could get some hints while I keep trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the "crop" function of this library :

"https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html".

I would probably use this function to get the required area as an image, and then use that resultant image -> load it as a data frame -> then do the further processing/statistics.